# Count across two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with two tables, bookings and users.
They are linked via a foreign key `user_id` in the bookings table.

How would I go about showing the number of bookings per user.

I've been trying variations on this query:

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*) 
from bookings 
left join users on bookings.user_id 
group by user_id 
order by count(*);
```

But it's locking the database for an incredibly long time.

Comment: can you add the output of running EXPLAIN SELECT first_name, last_name, count(\*) FROM bookings LEFT JOIN users ON bookings.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count(\*);

Comment: Have you tried setting an alias name for `count(*)` and using that in the `order by` clause? Might speed up the process.

Comment: 1 SIMPLE bookings index NULL fk_user_bookings 4 NULL 37672 Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE users ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 32594

Comment: That would be clearer if you paste the output into the question itself, and indent by four space so that it stays preformatted.

Also, add the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE bookings; and SHOW CREATE TABLE users;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your ON clause is not complete. Usually it will be `ON X=Y`, you have `ON X`. THis is important because you are telling the database how to link your two tables. I'm guessing this is where the most time is lost.

Second, the LEFT JOIN as used here is useless (unless you want the bookings that have no users.) Try an INNER JOIN.

Third, as a general rule, it's better to do `SmallTable INNER JOIN BigTable` (not always, your mileage may vary.)

Fourth, as mentioned, use an alias for the ORDER BY clause.

Try:

```
select first_name, last_name, count(*) as cnt
from users
inner join bookings on bookings.user_id = user.id
group by user_id
order by cnt;
```

Comment: @KJF I just realized, this won't return zero entries, where cnt=0. Only 1 and up. Did you need zeroes too?

Comment: No, there was no need to add zeros. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select group by in the books:

```
select user_id, count(1) from bookings group by user_id;
```

And then if you need the name, etc, join this sub-select with the users table